# Rails console warning rvm already initialized constant Rails::Command::HELP_MAPPINGS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

Getting a weird console warning recently, thought I'd try and clear it out.

When I go to my rails project folder, and run the Mac Terminal command:

```
rails test
```

I get the following warning:

```
/Users/zhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:18: warning: already initialized constant Rails::Command::HELP_MAPPINGS 

/Users/zhang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:18: warning: previous definition of HELP_MAPPINGS was here
```

I am using RVM.

If I run `rvm gemset list` I get:

```
gemsets for ruby-2.3.1 (found in /Users/zhang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1)
   (default)
=> global
```

If I run `rvm list` I get:

```
rvm rubies

   ruby-2.3.0 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.3.1 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-head [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

The command `ruby --version` outputs:

```
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin15]
```

The command `rails --version` outputs:

```
Rails 5.1.4
```

Any ideas on how I can get rid of the warnings?